# Where to place application settings for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm working on a WPF application in which i need to read and update application settings, p.e. the user language for the GUI.
Shall i create a new config-file which is copied to the output directory or the standard app.config?
In case of app.config it would meen to change the copy-mode to "Copy to output directory".
What's the best choice?

Comment: I would recommend using the app.config because it's designed to store the application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example use `Application.Current.Properties`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348545(v=vs.100).aspx

Or you could use the `Settings` class if you require the settings to be edited during runtime and saved across runs: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf/